# Adding Jekyll collections prevent posts from rendering

Tags: jekyll

I have a strange problem where adding collections and `collections_dir` allows me to get one result where I can view the collection results on the `ML Projects` page that you can see in the sidebar of my website but it prevents any posts in `_posts` from rendering.

After doing some research I learned that posts is a collection by default, but I'm not sure how this helps me. I tried moving the `_posts` directory into the `_projects` directory, which is my `collections_dir`, but that does not work.

To replicate issue:

1. Clone the repo at https://github.com/luke-anglin/lukes_site
2. Build and serve the site, noting that posts do render
3. Go to `_config.yml` and remove the comments on line 26-29 which specify the collection and the collections_dir
4. Rebuild and see that the posts disappear, but the collection things work.

`config.yml`

```yaml
# Dependencies
markdown:         kramdown

# Permalinks
permalink:        pretty

# Setup
title:            Luke Anglin
tagline:          Computer Science and Engineering Student
description:      Software Engineering, DevOps, Data Science
url:              http://localhost:4000/
baseurl:          /

author:
  name:           Luke Anglin
 # url:            https://twitter.com/mdo

plugins: 
 - jekyll-paginate

paginate:         5
paginate_path: 'page:num'

# Custom vars
# Collections 
# collections: 
#   - ml   

# collections_dir: _projects
version:          2.1.0

github:
  repo:           https://github.com/luke-anglin/lukes_site

defaults:
  - scope:
      path: 'static/assets/media'
    values:
      image: true
```

`index.html` where the posts are supposed to be looped through

```html
---
layout: default
title: Home
---

<div class="posts">
  {% for post in paginator.posts %}
  <div class="post">
    <h1 class="post-title">
      <a href="{{ post.url }}">
        {{ post.title }}
      </a>
    </h1>

    <span class="post-date">{{ post.date | date_to_string }}</span>

    {{ post.content }}
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>

<div class="pagination">
  {% if paginator.next_page %}
    <a class="pagination-item older" href="{{ site.baseurl }}page{{paginator.next_page}}">Older</a>
  {% else %}
    <span class="pagination-item older">Older</span>
  {% endif %}
  {% if paginator.previous_page %}
    {% if paginator.page == 2 %}
      <a class="pagination-item newer" href="{{ site.baseurl }}">Newer</a>
    {% else %}
      <a class="pagination-item newer" href="{{ site.baseurl }}page{{paginator.previous_page}}">Newer</a>
    {% endif %}
  {% else %}
    <span class="pagination-item newer">Newer</span>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

Any other info can be found in the repo. Let me know if there are any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the leading '_' from '_projects' directory. The 'collections_dir:' isn't allowed to have this character in the name of the target folder.

See: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/

Particularly the red notice labeled **'Be sure to move drafts and posts into custom collections directory'**. At the end it mentions *'Note that, the name of your collections directory cannot start with an underscore (`_`).'*

Hope this helps.